# check and auto re establish reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: amazon-s3, cron, ssh-tunnel, dyndns

I'm establishing a reverse tunnel with `$ ssh -fN -R 19999:localhost:22  -i aws-mycert.pem ubuntu@my.dyndns.com` and need to make sure it stays up & running even past a server reset. How can I check for the connection in a cron script that then re-establishes the connection autiomatically when required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is using Netcat. The command `nc -z localhost 19999` will check if there is something in the local port 19999 listening, so you could use: `nc -z localhost 19999 || ssh -fN -R 19999:localhost:22 -i aws-mycert.pem ubuntu@my.dyndns.com` to recreate the tunnel if needed.

However, this only checks that the tunnel is up, but it might be stale. The best solution is to use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/). Just install it in your machine and use:

`autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -fN -R 19999:localhost:22 -i aws-mycert.pem ubuntu@my.dyndns.com`

Then you just need to run this command when the server starts, which depends on your distribution.

You can find more details on using autossh at https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/.